# How to implement Ruby utility class methods?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Need help implementing Ruby **utility class methods** to get this test to pass. Can someone break this down for me please?

**My Code**

```
class Temperature

  class << self
    def from_fahrenheit temp
      Temperature.new({f: temp})
    end

    def from_celsius temp
      Temperature.new({c: temp})
    end
  end

  def initialize(options={})
    @f = options[:f]
    @c = options[:c]
  end

  def in_fahrenheit
    return @f if @f
    (@c * (9.0 / 5.0)) + 32
  end

  def in_celsius
    return @c if @c
    (@f - 32) * 5.0 / 9.0
  end
end

class Celsius < Temperature
  def initialize temp
    @temp = temp
  end
end

class Fahrenheit < Temperature
  def initialize temp
    @temp = temp
  end
end
```

**Failures:**

```
  1) Temperature Temperature subclasses Celsius subclass is constructed in degrees celsius
     Failure/Error: (@f - 32) * 5.0 / 9.0
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass
     # ./ct.rb:1118:in `in_celsius'
     # ./ct.rb:1219:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Temperature Temperature subclasses Fahrenheit subclass is constructed in degrees fahrenheit
     Failure/Error: (@c * (9.0 / 5.0)) + 32
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `*' for nil:NilClass
     # ./ct.rb:1113:in `in_fahrenheit'
     # ./ct.rb:1230:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**Rspec Test**

```
 describe "utility class methods" do

  end

  # Here's another way to solve the problem!
  describe "Temperature subclasses" do
    describe "Celsius subclass" do
      it "is constructed in degrees celsius" do
        Celsius.new(50).in_celsius.should == 50
        Celsius.new(50).in_fahrenheit.should == 122
      end

      it "is a Temperature subclass" do
        Celsius.new(0).should be_a(Temperature)
      end
    end

    describe "Fahrenheit subclass" do
      it "is constructed in degrees fahrenheit" do
        Fahrenheit.new(50).in_fahrenheit.should == 50
        Fahrenheit.new(50).in_celsius.should == 10
      end

      it "is a Temperature subclass" do
        Fahrenheit.new(0).should be_a(Temperature)
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't using the `Temperature` class how you defined it.  You take an `options` hash with `:f` and `:c` keys in it in the `Temperature` class, but don't set those in your sub-classes.

Try this:

```
class Celsius < Temperature
  def initialize temp
    super(c: temp)
  end
end

class Fahrenheit < Temperature
  def initialize temp
    super(f: temp)
  end
end
```

Is this for an exercise or something?  It's an ... interesting design.

Comment: Yes this is an exercise. Is calling `super` necessary? See my answer. It also passes the Rspec tests. By "interesting" do you mean horrendous? Because I admit I wrote this code without understanding how it works. I'm learning ruby and I'm chalking this exercise experience result up to subconscious coding.

Comment: Well, `Temperature` defines an interface by taking that options hash, and in your subclasses you are bypassing it and reaching up into that class and setting its variables.  Your solution ends up using 2 different ways of initializing the `@f` and `@c` variables, which is a bit confusing and error-prone.  All depends on whether that matters. :)

Comment: Just so I understand this, by using `super` in the subclasses I'm accessing the values of `f` and `c` initialized in the `Temperature` class. Without using `super` (as my answer below shows), I'm bypassing the initialized values in the `Temperature` class and I'm just setting them from within the `Celsius` and `Fahrenheit` classes respectively?